# How do I calculate an incomplete sinusoidal signal's average value and RMS value?

Tags: signal, math, rms, calculation

I couldn't be sure because there are parts with size 0 in the signal.

[image]

Comment: If it was DC how would you do it? Show your work and we'll give you some help. Can you capitalise your question title properly?

Comment: [Take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: size 0, or value of 0? Seems like your signal is periodic, what do you know about taking averages/RMS values of periodic signals?

Comment: @Michael, Vrms is apparent for 0<time<3t,and Vrms=0 for 3t<time<10t.
how do i combine the two for 0<time<10t?

Comment: Are you familiar with integration techniques? Namely splitting up a integral and evaluating it with two different bounds (instead of integrating from 0 to 10t, can integrate from 0 to 3t and 3t to 10t and add results.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the average by calculating the average of one positive half cycle of the sinusoidal waveform. Over one period that repeats the average will be 1/10 of that number, since the full cycle cancels out and the remaining 7 periods are zero.

The number (two 2 decimal places) will be about 0.064\$\cdot\$Vm, but you should work it out exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the RMS-value can be found using:

$$\text{V}_\text{RMS}:=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int\limits_0^\text{T}\left(\text{V}\left(x\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}x}\tag1$$

And, we can see that \$\text{T}=10t\$ and for the integral we can write:

$$\int\limits_0^\text{T}\left(\text{V}\left(x\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}x=2\int\limits_0^t\left(\text{V}\left(x\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}x+\int\limits_t^{2t}\left(\text{V}\left(x\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}x+\int\limits_{3t}^{10t}0^2\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

Where \$\text{V}\left(x\right)=\text{V}_\text{m}\sin\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{2t}\cdot x\right)=\text{V}_\text{m}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{t}\right)\$.

And you will/must find:

$$\text{V}_\text{RMS}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{m}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\approx0.3872983346\text{V}_\text{m}\tag3$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint or two on RMS value: -

- If you had a 100 watt load that is fed from the correct supply voltage, what would be the average power produced by that load if you turned on and off the supply voltage for equal time durations. Can you see that the average power will be 50 watts?
- If you had a resistive load (fed from AC) that that produces 100 watts, can you see that if you fed it via an ideal rectifier diode, the average power it would produce is only 50 watts?
- If you had a resistive load (fed from AC) that that produces 100 watts, can you see that if you fed it via an ideal **bridge rectifier**, the average power it would produce is still 100 watts?
- If you convert to a power waveform (by assuming a 1 Ω load), you can do the simple number crunching in watts then, convert back to RMS values (by assuming the same 1 Ω load).